# Is there an alternative to "revalue" function from plyr when using dplyr?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, plyr

I'm a fan of the `revalue` function is `plyr` for substituting strings. It's simple and easy to remember.

However, I've migrated new code to `dplyr` which doesn't appear to have a `revalue` function. What is the accepted idiom in `dplyr` for doing things previously done with `revalue`?

Comment: Can you show some reproducible example

Comment: `library(plyr); library(dplyr)`?

Comment: someone having same thoughts here https://twitter.com/jennybryan/status/524607056696057856

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a `recode` function available starting with *dplyr* version dplyr_0.5.0 which looks very similar to `revalue` from *plyr*.

Example built from the `recode` documentation *Examples* section:

```
set.seed(16)
x = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)
x
 [1] "a" "b" "a" "b" "b" "a" "c" "c" "c" "a"

recode(x, a = "Apple", b = "Bear", c = "Car")

   [1] "Car"   "Apple" "Bear"  "Apple" "Car"   "Apple" "Apple" "Car"   "Car"   "Apple"
```

If you only define some of the values that you want to recode, by default the rest are filled with `NA`.

```
recode(x, a = "Apple", c = "Car")
 [1] "Car"   "Apple" NA      "Apple" "Car"   "Apple" "Apple" "Car"   "Car"   "Apple"
```

This behavior can be changed using the `.default` argument.

```
recode(x, a = "Apple", c = "Car", .default = x)
 [1] "Car"   "Apple" "b"     "Apple" "Car"   "Apple" "Apple" "Car"   "Car"   "Apple"
```

There is also a `.missing` argument if you want to replace missing values with something else.

Comment: Apparently this is the Hadley endorsed answer: See https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/524614991719067648 and https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/631

Answer (score 5):

We can do this with `chartr` from `base R`

```
chartr("ac", "AC", x)
```

#### data

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: I love how you always post a `base R` solution; wherever I go, you are there @akrun +1. Additionally, how would you manage to do it with two long vectors? let's say as in the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36627361/10714156)

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas thank you.  I looked at the link you showed.  It is showing a single vector.  Any chance the link is different

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment on the answer by @aosmith, but lack reputation. It seems that nowadays the default of `dplyr`'s `recode` function is to leave unspecified levels unaffected.

```
x = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)
x
[1] "c" "c" "b" "b" "a" "b" "c" "c" "c" "b"

recode(x , a = "apple", b = "banana" )

[1] "c"      "c"      "banana" "banana" "apple"  "banana" "c"      "c"      "c"      "banana"
```

To change all nonspecified levels to `NA`, the argument `.default = NA_character_` should be included.

```
recode(x, a = "apple", b = "banana", .default = NA_character_)

[1] "apple"  "banana" "apple"  "banana" "banana" "apple"  NA       NA       NA       "apple"
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative that I find handy is the mapvalues function for the data.tables
e.g

```
df[, variable := mapvalues(variable, old = old_names_string_vector, new = new_names_string_vector)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**R base solution**

You can use `ifelse()` from `base` for this. The functions arguments are `ifelse(test, yes, no)`. Here an example:

```
(x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 5, replace = TRUE))
[1] "c" "a" "b" "a" "a"

ifelse(x == "a", "Apple", x)
[1] "c"     "Apple" "b"     "Apple" "Apple"
```

If you want to recode multiple values you can use the function in a nested way like this:

```
ifelse(x == "a", "Apple", ifelse(x == "b", "Banana", x))
[1] "c"      "Apple"  "Banana" "Apple"  "Apple"
```

**Own function**

Having many values that must be recoded can make coding with `ifelse()` messy. Therefor, Ihere is an own function:

```
my_revalue <- function(x, ...){
  reval <- list(...)

  from <- names(reval)
  to <- unlist(reval)

  out <- eval(parse(text= paste0("{", paste0(paste0("x[x ==", "'", from,"'", "]", "<-", "'", to, "'"), collapse= ";"), ";x", "}")))

  return(out)
}
```

Now we can change multiple values quite fast:

```
my_revalue(vec= x, "a" = "Apple", "b" = "Banana", "c" = "Cranberry")
[1] "Cranberry" "Apple"     "Banana"      "Apple"     "Apple"
```