# Replace region numbers with names

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
regions_numbers <- c(2,9,21,142,150,419)
regions_names <- c("Oceania", "Africa", "North America", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America")
```

I need to replace the numbers with their corresponding region name but I'm unsure what code to use

Comment: To clarify, you are saying you want to replace the number "2" with "Oceania". Or say, "150" with "Europe". So if then, we introduce a new vector with say `eg<-c(142,142,142)` you want a new vector where instead it says `c("Asia","Asia","Asia")` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. each of those numbers corresponds to the respective region

Comment: The numbers are in a column called "Region." I want to replace the numbers in the column with the corresponding names

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways, but off the top of my head I would resort to using dataframes. That way we can do things like `left_join` which does the mapping (similar to vlookup) in excel.

We start off by creating a mapping dataframe:

```
df_region = data.frame(regions_numbers = c(2,9,21,142,150,419),
                      regions_names = c("Oceania", "Africa", "North America", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America"))
```

Now, we can do the mapping, by converting any future vector into a dataframe as well:

```
new_region_numbers = data.frame(regions_numbers  = sample(c(2,9,21,142,150,419),10,replace = TRUE))
```

The `sample` just gives me a random set of `region_numbers`. Now by using `left_join`, we easily get the mapping you want:

```
new_region_names =new_region_numbers %>% 
  left_join(df_region, by = c("regions_numbers" = "regions_numbers"))
```

with output:

```
  regions_numbers regions_names
1              142          Asia
2              142          Asia
3              150        Europe
4                9        Africa
5              150        Europe
6              150        Europe
7               21 North America
8               21 North America
9              419 Latin America
10             150        Europe
```

and if you **only** want the vector then you can select it by saying:

```
new_names_only = new_region_names$regions_names
```

That's one way of doing it. I'm sure there a more "inbuilt" functions for doing these kinds of mapping. But can't think of any at the moment.

Comment: `dplyr::recode()` does the same. **Left Join** would be too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way, tidy way...

```
sample_vec <- sample(regions_numbers, 20, replace = TRUE)
recode(sample_vec, "2" = "Oceania", "9" = "Africa", "21" = "North America",
           "142" = "Asia", "150" = "Europe", "419" = "Latin America")
```

Useful [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615769/is-there-an-alternative-to-revalue-function-from-plyr-when-using-dplyr)