# Factorizing leads to NA

Tags: r

I have the following table. With 'a' and 'b' on a likert scale from 1-5.

| type | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| typeOne | 2 | 3 |
| typeTwo | 4 | 4 |
| typeOne | 5 | 2 |

Now I try to visualize the data as seen here in two groups (typeOne, typeTwo) and with 'a' and 'b' on the y-axis.

[image: Likert Example Image]

Unfortunately when I run my factor code all numeric values vanish from the table and get replaced by 'NA'.

My code is:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(data) 

factorLevels <- c('Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neither', 'Agree', 'Strongly Agree') 

df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], factor, levels=factorLevels) 

library(likert)
df_likert <- likert(df[,c(2:3)], grouping = df$type) 
plot(df_likert)
```

When I run the plot command I get the following error:

> argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

Comment: You will need use revalue or other alternative function to turn your integers into string values first, see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615769/is-there-an-alternative-to-revalue-function-from-plyr-when-using-dplyr

Comment: You shouldn't turn them into factors.  Are you using the likert package?

Comment: @Elin Yes, I am using the likert package

Comment: Okay that does not want factors, it wants you to assign the labels using its own special methods.  Look at https://lmudge13.github.io/sample_code/likert_graphs.html     ... You need `ordered=TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `levels=` with `labels=`.

```
fac <- c('a', 'b')

f_labels <- c('Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neither', 'Agree', 
              'Strongly Agree')

d[fac] <- lapply(d[fac], factor, levels=1:5, labels=f_labels)

library(likert)
d_likert <- likert(d[fac], grouping=d$type) 
plot(d_likert)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
d <- read.table(text='type  a   b
typeOne     2   3
typeTwo     4   4
typeOne     5   2', header=TRUE)
```